# Add WWW at Joomla's URL without redirect to index

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I'm using Joomla and I need to add www in all url's from the website.

We have *Facebook's Comments Plugin installed*, and turns out when you access the website for example: www.mysite.com.br/category/k2-item-500 it shows some comments, but if you access the same page without 'www', the plugin shows different comments because urls are not the same.

**What I need is:**

When visitors access mywebsite.com/category/page
The htaccess automatically add www into the URL.

I've found some solutions but all them despite add WWW as well also redirect to index.php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as the first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```